# Managing Autogenerated Indexes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm doing an advanced search like the one detailed in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection

I'm increasing the number of filters from 2 to 4, with 4 sort orders. If I create a perfect index on this search, I'll need 64 indexes in my index.yaml. I followed the advice in the Advanced Search article and created basic indexes for each filter and sort order resulting in 20 indexes. I tested that these indexes satisfy my search by running my development server with dev_appserver.py --require_indexes

If I go back to my regular development workflow and run just the dev_appserver.py, accessing my search page creates the perfect indexes. I don't want to give up the ability to generate indexes for other aspects of development by always running with --require_indexes. I also don't want the dev server to create these extra indexes either. Is there a way to have the server only create new indexes if it would otherwise raise a NeedIndexError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to obtain your (very sensible and useful!) required functionality with the dev appserver.

I believe it **would** be feasible to add and support a new flag to it, similar to but "softer than" `--require_indexes`, with exactly the semantics you suggest -- update `index.yaml` "as needed" *but* only as a last-ditch fall-back against what would otherwise be a `NeedIndexError`.

However I would discourage developing this as a fork of the SDK (which would be perfectly legal given its open-source license, but unwise since carrying the patches forward as new SDKs get released would soon become pretty troublesome:-).

Rather I would -- first and foremost -- open a feature request on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list .

Next, I'd suggest you either (A) save your carefully handcrafted `index.yaml` and accordingly edit/trim the bloated auto-generated one before deploying, or (B) run with `--require_indexes` and patiently hand-edit `index.yaml` as required (whether once a `NeedIndexError` traceback has told you so, or preventively as you realized you've added some new query.

Yes it's nowhere as fun as editing the SDK to add and support a new flag, but... it will probably serve your app's needs better!

Comment: I contacted premium support and they opened an feature request for me:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11666&q=index&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log